# cannot find symbol in Android Studio without rebuilding project

Tags: android, android-studio, symbols

When I try to deploy my project to the emulator the compile fails with a bunch of Cannot find symbol errors. I have to rebuild the project then deploy everytime I make a change. This just started in 0.1.6 for me. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Someone from google mentioned: As a temporary workaround, try turning off Preferences > Compiler > Use External Build.

Comment: I seem to have new problems with every version of Android Studio.  I realize it is in beta, but you would think a company as big as Google could do regression testing before deploying a new version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, try turning off Preferences > Compiler > Use External Build.

(as suggested in this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56884)

Comment: There is no "Use External Build" option in 0.3.1. I'm not sure which version removed it.

Comment: If you modify the id of a view in one of your layout files that will force Android Studio to rebuild the R file before running. I use this workaround to bypass having to rebuild.

Answer (score 7):

Clicking "Sync project with Gradle files" resolved this for me.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I used the following answer and it worked great:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19223269/1531683

You can do "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Just Click **Build -> Clean Project**. It will solve the problem of missing "R.java".

Answer (score 2):

Same here. Check this for updates: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56884&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: the issue has been merged with https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56843&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, deleting the out folder before rebuilding the project solves the problem!

Comment: someone from google commented in the bug thread and said the only real workaround right now is what csongor suggested

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following into the dependencies worked for me:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Using java 7 inner classes instead of lambda functions provided by [retro-lambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) solved my issue.