# Android studio: getting lots of cannot resolve symbol error after running inspect code

Tags: android-studio

my project was running correctly in android studio 0.1.7 (in eclipse also). I have just run the inspect code option. after that whenever i am trying to build my project i am getting 33 "cannot resolve symbol class " type errors and now i am not able to build my project. but still its working fine in eclipse.

Comment: I'm having the very same issue. To get it properly resolved I think we have to wait on google to release a new update.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem with android studio causing cannot resolve symbol errors right now. Google has suggested turning off Preferences > Compiler > Use external build as a workaround.

[cannot find symbol in Android Studio without rebuilding project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241855/cannot-find-symbol-in-android-studio-without-rebuilding-project)