# Android studio Gradle BUILD SUCCESSFUL despite cannot resolve android.support.v4

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, build-tools

Despite Gradle is telling me build succesfull (and I can run the app), android studio cannot resolve "import android.support.v4" and for the support.v7 lib can only resolve appcompat... I tried the button "Use Sync project with gradle files", upgraded my build tools to the latest version but I still have this error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Please help me fix this!

Comment: I am having the same problem, have you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly no.. I'm going crazy with this :(

Comment: As a temporary solution I fall back to using 22.0.0. and it work as usual.

Comment: For me it's not working even with the 22.0.0... It's weird becahuse I can launch the app and I have 0 build errors..

Comment: I simply made a new project and copied all the files from the old one. Now is working.. I really don't know what happaned :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio says "cannot resolve symbol" but project compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508649/android-studio-says-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

- Run all updates: Update android studio and SDK to the latest version.
- go to File->invalidate caches/Restart.

Hope this fixes the problem.