# Cannot access GooglePlayServicesClient

Tags: android, google-play-services

For some reason I can't get GooglePlayServicesClient to work. I have followed the [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#Install) guide. `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` is in the correct `build.gradle` file. I ran "Sync Project with Gradle Files". In the SDK Manager, I have installed Extras > Google Play services rev 25. On a clean build, I get the following errors:

```
Error:(20, 24) error: cannot access GooglePlayServicesClient
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient not found

Error:(24, 28) error: cannot access OnConnectionFailedListener
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$OnConnectionFailedListener not found

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I've double checked that I followed the setup guide correctly, uninstalled and reinstalled the Google Play services from the SDK Manager, closed and reopened Android Studio, all with no success.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

GooglePlayServiceClient no longer exist in 7.5, check latest [guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), use GoogleApiClient instead

Comment: That would have been kind of Google to note that the guide I was looking at has been deprecated. Anyway, on the imports, eg. `import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;` it gives the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'android'"?

Comment: i can import it properly. try to clean and build project

Comment: Yeah. I've tried everything suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508649/android-studio-says-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles). I even created a new project, added the import and it still failed. I deleted the .gradle and .idea folders then reimported the new project. No success. I may either need to use old libraries that don't require com.google.android imports, or give up.