# Android Studio 1.5 and Android Annotations (by excilys)

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations, android-gradle-plugin

I have just updated my Android Studio to version 1.5 (latest available for this time).
But in my project I am using [Android Annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki). The problem, that I cannot compile my project, it doesn't recognize generated classes by Android Annotations plugin. The greater part of the project is now underlined with red color (error `Cannot resolve symbol`).
My colleges have the same problem with new Android Studio and Android Annotations.

Is there any solution for this problem available now ? Or the best way is to downgrade studio ?

**EDIT**

After invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio project was built, but still all generated classes underlined as an error (`Cannot resolve symbol`)

Comment: maybe your gradle files have been changed?

Comment: No gradle files are the same as they were. Not only I have such problem, all my colleges have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try in **command-line** `gradle clean` and `gradle build` outside AndroidStudio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508649/android-studio-says-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles