# Android Studio AdMob Integration error

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I am trying to add admob features to my application. I have followed [Google admob guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start).
When I load the ad in the MainActivity class, I have the following error.
I attached a screenshot of the code.How to fix this issue?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-96568545160124~214045445");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show your gradle file.Have you added this line       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0

Comment: ya i added that line in to build.gradle file as a dependencies.I followed all the steps in google admob setup tutorial.

Comment: I assume your project is getting compiled successfully only errors are displayed on Android Studio. Try solutions provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508649/android-studio-says-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles

Answer (score 0):

Try Syncing the Gradle again. I also got stuck sometimes but it got fixed by removing some character from firebase dependency from Gradle and put it again, then sync the Gradle. 
P.S. Worked for me.