# Cannot resolve symbol animation

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error in the below two import statements

```
import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
```

Android Studio is showing cannot resolve symbol animation

Answer (score 1):

Try:
"File" -> "Invalidate Caches..."

Look at this question too (probably a duplicate of):
[Android Studio says "cannot resolve symbol" but project compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508649/android-studio-says-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles)

Also check if you have imported the animation class in your class.