# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol - Build works

Tags: android-studio

today AndroidStudio started acting up, not being able to resolve android.support.vx symbols anymore.

What I did shortly before: trying to clean up my C drive, and erroneously deleting the .android folder, as well as moving my SDK folder.

Issues are had with

```
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

the relevant part in gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "not.for.public.eyes"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.21"
        //versionNameSuffix '-TEST'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        /*jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }*/
    }

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    //        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    //    })
    compile files('src/main/libs/eidlib.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

What I have tried to resolve the issue:

1. clean gradle build
2. reinstall android studio
3. invalidate caches

it worked without issue untill just before, but now it shows red always.
Weird thing though: build still works, run on connected device still works.

all help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910140/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles-and-works/47918062#47918062) post, I found the solution.

1. clean build(Build menu)
2. invalidate cache(no restart) (File Menu)
3. remove .gradle and .idea folders (View Menu > Tool Windows > Project >> Project pane, somewhere at the top probably)
4. restart Android Studio

Possibly you can finetune this, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! My android studio has been stuck for the past 4 hours, with it being unable to build, and not even cleaning, invalidating and restarting fixed the problem. After deleting the two folder the project build successfully again. I though I was going crazy :P

Comment: none of that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and restart didn't work for me.
removing and adding dependencies worked for me.
1: Removing all dependencies from app/build.gradle and Sync.
2: Add all again and Sync.