# The project is built successfully, the app is running but R class stays in red

Tags: java, android

I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project but it didn't help. I also don't have any errors in my XML file. When I run the app it works but R class stays in red. Please help me.

Comment: File->Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Also, try to make the project @Shams

Comment: You might have androidX related issue, please migrate to latest version of android studio,

Comment: Its Probably a gradle Version issue . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360220/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but-project-compiles-and-runs..

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes
do:

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Also "Sync with file system" or "Sync project with Gradle files" might help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I solved this problem change gradle version. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' in build.gradle