# iText document - resolve symbol

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText in android app to create pdf.

```
 try{

        File file=new File("test.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream(file);
        Document document=new Document();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this gives an error (Document abstract class - cannot be instantiated).

Even after importing `import com.itextpdf.text.Document;`

It shows this thing:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'itextpdf'
```

document is displayed as error.

Any solution?

Comment: Seems like package itextpdf is not being resolved. Did you add it to your dependencies?

Comment: compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'    ->After adding this dependency it gave this error->Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10.

Comment: Clear all imports and try again

Comment: com.itextpdf.text.Document is not abstract class so it should be instantiated

Comment: One of my friend changed build variants and it worked somehow.IDK how though

Answer (score 0):

First have to add "compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'" in gradle properties.

Second you could try:

- Exit Android Studio
- Back up your project
- Delete all the .iml files and the .idea folder
- Relaunch Android Studio and re-import your project

By the way, the error messages you see in the Project Structure dialog are not actual issue for the most part.

Comment: compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.0.6'    ->add this under dependencies of gradle app?

Comment: Please add in build.gradle file, dependencies {
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
}

Answer (score 0):

For first error try with

```
 try{

    File file=new File("test.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream(file);
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document=new com.itextpdf.text.Document();


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'itextpdf'
```

[Android Studio says "cannot resolve symbol" but project compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508649/android-studio-says-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-project-compiles)