# cannot resolve symbol fragmentcontainer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

So I've decide to go back into android developing after dropping it for a bit. I Restarted making an old project in android studio I ran into a issue where I'm getting "cannot resolve symbol fragmentcontainer" and I'm sure it was working last time.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // add fragment to the activity
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // give fragment to manage
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `Activity` layout `R.layout.activity_main` does not contain a view with id `fragmentContainer`. If that's not the issue, check this related question: [Android Studio cannot resolve symbol but code executes correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991161/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-code-executes-correctly).

Answer (score 0):

just using "fragment_container" not "android.R.id.fragment_container" works for me...here is the detail

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(fragment_container, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commitNow();` instead of using `R.id.fragmentContainer` to create fragment in an activity.