# Android studio cannot resolve symbol equals

Tags: java, android-studio

I am making a simple mobile app. For now I am just testing the app and trying to pass some values in between java files and put them in empty `TextView`s. I get values from a previous activity via `Intent` and then trying to pass them on to another activity called `ConsultActivity.java`:

```
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Identifiant");
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVUsername);
if(username.equals("marcel123")){
    tv.setText("M Dupond");
}
else if(username.equals("tommy1")){
    tv.setText("M Thompson");
}
else if(username.equals("emma89")){
    tv.setText("Mme Sinieux");
}

consult = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.consult);

consult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ConsultActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Username", tv.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

However in my `ConsultActivity`, when I am doing basically the same thing, my `equals` are highlighted and say "Cannot resolve symbol equals"

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");
final TextView textV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVUsername2);
if(name.equals("M Dupond")){
    textV.setText("M Dupond");
}
else if(name.equals("M Thompson")){
    textV.setText("M Thompson");
}
else if(name.equals("Mme Sinieux")){
    textV.setText("Mme Sinieux");
}
```

Comment: Try to clean your project maybe ? Build -> Clean Project

Comment: Also clean Android Studio cache. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19223269/1349601

Comment: Tried that, didn't help

Comment: Is it working when you run the code ?

Comment: What are your imports for ConsultActivity?

Comment: Is isn't as there are errors

Comment: @peteBelford import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: Do any other common string functions work?  That is really weird dude.  .equals is defined for Object.

Comment: * The same question as David, Is it working when you run the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably its just a Synchronization problem try with: **`Sych project with gradle files`**

[image]