# Android KeyEvent Class not working ?Cannot resolve symbol 'KeyEvent'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keyevent

when i am trying to insert key events in  android import android.view.KeyEvent; is not working, got this Cannot resolve symbol 'KeyEvent' when import java lib.

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;

 view.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.pause)
                            .setTitle("PAUSE")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Pause this test?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //finish();
                                }

                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                            .show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

Cannot resolve symbol 'KeyEvent'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are importing this *Outside* your class? Can you show the whole class?

Comment: import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;@ZohaibAmir

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991161/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-code-executes-correctly