# Android: Cannot find symbol variable error

Tags: android

I am running into a weird issue! I have id names for each layout in my xml file and I created variable references to them in my main activity . java file.

When I clean and rebuild my project I get this:

"error: cannot find symbol layoutMain = findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);"

no idea why.... first time I see this...

I am using min. SDK 21, target of 29

see images:
[image: MAIN ACTIVITY JAVA]

[image: GRADLE]

[image: XML MAIN ACTIVITY]

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991161/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-code-executes-correctly

Comment: Yes, usually an issue with cached ids. `Invalidate cache and restart` often helps.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `implementation "com.google.android.material..."`  ? try to comment the alpha one

Comment: I was desperately hoping that, that would solve my issue! but didn't.... I created a dummy android app with the same programming and it worked... SO WEIRD! I also removed the implementation but didn't do anything

Comment: I just realized that I have 2 layouts called "main_activity" 1 is the original and the other is (v21), could that be causing the issue???

Answer (score 1):

Probably Android Studio bugged and is having problems with ids.

Try to `Invalidate caches and restart`. Go to `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate caches and restart`

This will delete Android Studio caches and recreate them.

Comment: I was desperately hoping that, that would solve my issue! but didn't.... I created a dummy android app with the same programming and it worked... SO WEIRD!

Comment: Oh okay. Sometimes this happens, maybe some corrupted files. If this happens again try to import your project by `Import an existing project` option in Android Studio. This worked for me sometimes.

Comment: I just realized that I have 2 layouts called "main_activity" 1 is the original and the other is (v21), could that be causing the issue???

Comment: I don't thinks so. One question, do you have this problem on other android studio projects?

Comment: no. any way I just started from scratch and it works as intended! thank you for putting up with me!

Comment: Yes, I was going to tell you to do this. The last thing to do is to create a new project and copy all your files. Or to import your existing project. Good programming! :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, nothing helped. I deleted the cache, rebuilt the project, changed the names.
The solution for me was to **create a new project and just copy everything from the old one**.