# Cannot find symbol variable when building apk

Tags: android, apk

I am getting error messages when I try building a release apk and this has only started happening since I changed the build variant to `release` instead of `debug`.

So I have had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) and I had a look at all the things that could be causing my error but I just can't seem to find the problem with my code. **I assume this post is going to get flagged as a duplicate but I prefer having another programmer look at my code and then I can resolve the problem from there**. I really would appreciate if someone could do that for me. Here is the code, the errors I receive from the Gradle Build and my import library:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button mbtnLogin;
private Button mbtnForgetPassword;
private TextView mTextStateOnline;
private EditText minputEmail;
private EditText minputPassword;
private ProgressDialog mpDialog;
private Switch mSwitch;
public static SQLiteHandler sDb;
public static FileManager fileManager;
public static User sUserco;
public static int sRank;
public static boolean sOnline=true;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //-----------------Set up manager--------------
    fileManager = new FileManager(this);

    //-----------------Find View--------------
    minputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    minputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mbtnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    mbtnForgetPassword = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Login_forget_pasword);
    mTextStateOnline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Login_state_online);
    mSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
```

Messages from Gradle Build:

```
M:\Live Projects\IT\Projects\Ghana app\Source Code\Mednet_Ghana\app\src\main\java\co\uk\mednet\mednet_ghana\activity\LoginActivity.java
Error:(81, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable activity_login
Error:(87, 51) error: cannot find symbol variable email
Error:(88, 54) error: cannot find symbol variable password
Error:(89, 47) error: cannot find symbol variable btnLogin
Error:(90, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable Login_forget_pasword
Error:(91, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable Login_state_online
Error:(92, 45) error: cannot find symbol variable switch2
```

Import Libs:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.R;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.app.AppConfig;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.app.AppController;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.helper.FileManager;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.Answer;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.AssessmentFile;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.Lesson;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.Question;
import co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.User;
```

Comment: post your import libs also. i think you have static import (it causes view may not be in your current layout file) if yes remove that may help you.

Comment: this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/17241855/4146722

Comment: Clean-Rebuild your IDE

Comment: Sorry, neither of those suggestions have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply fixed this by going to my `Project_Name\Module_Name\build\outputs\apk\`.  I then deleted the apk that was in there, restarted android studio and went to `Build>Generate Signed APK`. I chose `Generate Signed APK` because that is what I needed to upload the APK to **Google Play Console**. I'm sure this will be transferable to the same problem, just as long as you Build Apk instead of the signed apk which requires more steps.